# Web access of Prolog database

Tags: prolog, database-connection

Is it possible to use Prolog as a database and host it on internet servers for users to access it over the web. There needs to be a html forms page where users can enter data. In addition, there needs to be another html forms page where user can enter query to be sent over internet to get response from Prolog database.

What is the best way to achieve such a setup? Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 4):

There are many possible ways to do this.

A simple and obvious way is to use Prolog **CGI scripts**. These scripts can parse any HTTP `GET` or `POST` request and respond after running arbitrary queries over Prolog clauses. See for example the SWI-Prolog [**cgi**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cgi) library. The idea carries over to other Prolog systems too of coures.

In SWI-Prolog, a different and very interesting approach is to use [**Pengines**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/pengines.html%27)).

That being said, there are dozens of variants to embed or include Prolog queries as part of other approaches, using interface libraries, pipes or other protocols for communication.

So, your web application efforts will definitely *not* be stopped due to a lack of options.